# If no image is uploaded, don't display placeholder image

Tags: html, shopify

If no image is uploaded from the Settings panel, then I don't want the default placeholder image to show (the no image picture which is currently there.

[image]

Here is the html code:

```
     <div class="Images">
      <div class="image1">
      <img src="{{section.settings.image1 | img_url: '120x120'}}"/>
      </div>
        <div class="image2">
      <img src="{{section.settings.image2 | img_url: '120x120'}}"/>
      </div>
        <div class="image3">
      <img src="{{section.settings.image3 | img_url: '120x120'}}"/>
      </div>
        <div class="image4">
      <img src="{{section.settings.image4 | img_url: '120x120'}}"/>
      </div>
        <div class="image5">
      <img src="{{section.settings.image5 | img_url: '120x120'}}"/>
      </div>
        <div class="image6">
      <img src="{{section.settings.image6 | img_url: '120x120'}}"/>
      </div>   
     </div>
```

The Schema code:

```
  {
              "type":"image_picker",
              "label":"image 1",
              "id":"image1"
              },
              {
              "type":"image_picker",
              "label":"image 2",
              "id":"image2"
              },
              {
              "type":"image_picker",
              "label":"image 3",
              "id":"image3"
              },
              {
              "type":"image_picker",
              "label":"image 4",
              "id":"image4"
              },
              {
              "type":"image_picker",
              "label":"image 5",
              "id":"image5"
              },
              {
              "type":"image_picker",
              "label":"image 6",
              "id":"image6"
              },
```

How do I make it work, so that if there is no image uploaded, then there should be no placeholder?

Comment: simply wrap the code into if condition and check if the image is added then add the img tag otherwise not. ` {% if section.settings.image1 != blank %}img tag goes here{% endif %}`

Comment: Thanks- that worked.  Is there a better way for me to code it, for e.g. if there is only 2 images, then then 2 images are central? currently if there is 2 images, there is a blank space for the other 4 images (if that makes sense) it makes the layout seem weird.

Comment: Take a look about some idea https://gist.github.com/o-nkar/a5bb4669d9ebf85a78b6c7ca35c31e94

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple as that:

```
{% if section.settings.image1 %}
    <div class="image1">
        <img src="{{section.settings.image1 | img_url: '120x120'}}"/>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```